# WPF Combobox Binding SelectedItem Not Sending Changes to Datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am fairly new to WPF and MVVM.  I have created a custom control that contains a Combobox.  I have bound the ItemSource and it works find, and the selectedItem sets correctly from the binding but when I change the Item it does not update the property.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**ComboboxUserControl.xaml**

```
<ComboBox ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemContainerStyle1}"
                  x:Name="comboBox"
                  Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  Foreground="{StaticResource InputFontColor}"
                  FontSize="16"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                  Height="30"
                  Margin="0"
                  Padding="0"
                  Grid.Column="2" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ElementName=UtilityComboBoxControl}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="{Binding DisplayMemberPath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ElementName=UtilityComboBoxControl}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

**ComboboxUserControl.xaml.cs**

```
        public string DisplayMemberPath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayMemberPath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMemberPath", typeof(string), typeof(UtilityCombobox), new PropertyMetadata(""));



        public IEnumerable  ItemSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(UtilityCombobox), new PropertyMetadata(null));



        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(UtilityCombobox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

On load it gets the property and sets the SelectedItem, but it does not do it inversely.

Comment: What property is not set when...?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question which property you expect to be set and when, but maybe you want to set the default mode of your custom dependency property to `TwoWay`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(UtilityCombobox), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

If you don't do this, you need to explicitly specify the mode of each binding to it, e.g.:

```
<local:ComboboxUserControl SelectedItem="{Binding SourceProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
```